# Can I put a prototype in an object literal?

Tags: javascript

Am I allowed to declare prototypes in an object literal?

```
var Obj = function(){
  var private = "Oh hi there I'm a private variable";
  return {
    init : function(param){
        this.param = 
        return this;
    }
    prototype.sayHi: function(){
        console.log("HI");
    }
  }
}
```

Would I now be able to call "Obj.sayHi"? Or is there a way to do this if the example is not possible?

Comment: You have a lot of problems here: First is that `private` can't be used as an identifier as it is a reserved word, `this.param =` is not continued. And that part where it says `prototype.sayHi:` is not valid syntax...

Comment: Yeah I tried to fix it in my answer but then realized I wasn't sure I knew what the question was anymore.

Comment: @David I didn't know private was reserved in `javascript`. What I was asking was if `prototype.sayHi` was valid at all, because I know I'm able to define `Obj.prototype.sayHi` outside the object literal. I was wondering if defining `prototype.sayHi` was valid inside an object literal. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Object literals ( `{ }` ) don't have an interal [[Prototype]] property like functions, so you can't do it that way. What you *can* do, however, is use `Object.create( obj )` like this: `var a = {}; var b = Object.create(a);`. Now `b` has the properties (if any) that `a` has.

Comment: thanks David, you and Guffa cleared things up quite a lot for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a local function to create the object with a prototype:

```
var Obj = function() {

    var private = "Oh hi there I'm a private variable";

    function create() {
        this.param = 42;
    }

    create.prototype = {

        sayHi: function() {
            console.log(private + this.param);
        }

    };

    return new create();

};

var x = Obj();
x.sayHi();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/pZQnU/

Answer (score 0):

Just try it in a JavaScript console. Since your example is full of syntax erors, try and run the following:

```
var myObj = {
   prototype.blarg: function() { return 'blarg'; }
};
```

You'll get:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can manually set the prototype of an object created using literal syntax, the official answer is no.

There *is* a non-standard syntax that lets you change the prototype of an object. It's the `__proto__` property, but again, it is non-standard right now.

```
var Obj = function(){
    var priv = "Oh hi there I'm a private variable";
    var o = {
       init : function(param){
           this.param = param;
           return this;
       }
    };

    o.__proto__ = {
        sayHi: function(){
            console.log("HI");
        }
    };
    return o;
}
```

Again, this is *non-standard*, so beware.

Comment: Where did you define `obj`? Perhaps you meant `return o;`. The variable `priv` is not used.

Comment: @RobG: In my imagination. ;-) I did a last minute variable name change so that I didn't have `obj` and `Obj`, but forgot that one. I'll update. Thanks. :) The `priv` is just the variable from the original code. Not essential to the answer, but I left it in just so that I could show a valid variable identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you recreate the prototype object / overwrite it, you should reset the constructor property because that will get overridden with Function().

```
var Person = function() {};
Person.prototype = {
    constructor: Person,
    someMethod: function() {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you're not understanding:

- prototype isn't a property specific to the object. It's a property of the function used to make it.
- In this case, the thing that makes object literals has a role to play in making everything in JavaScript

You can access the prototype directly from the constructor property in any object and in most cases at least add properties (but you can't typically replace the entire prototype of a core native object constructor). In the case of an object literal, it would be like this:

```
var obj = {};

//BIG NOTE: don't do this in real code. Just goof around in a console or a test project
obj.constructor.prototype.sayHi = function(){ console.log('HI'); }

var anotherObj = {};
anotherObj.sayHi(); //'HI'
```

So, Yay right? But here's the problem. These also work:

```
'bob'.sayHi();
[].sayHi();
new Date().sayHi();
document.sayHi();
(6).sayHi();//have to put 6 in parens because it handles '.' differently
```

Object literals are made with the core Object constructor function. The object constructor has a simple instance used as the prototype at the beginning of a prototype chain for just about every conceivable thing in JavaScript. Nobody has been doing this since prototype.js because there is heavy potential for seriously weird problems.

Generally speaking whatever you want to do with prototype might be something better attempted in a different direction. Setting your object literal as the prototype of a new function constructor. That way you have inheritance options without blowing up all the JS on the page.

It is generally considered a very bad idea to mess with the Object constructor's prototype. I would say Function.prototype is one you want to stay away from too. Object constructors that aren't used to build prototype objects for other native constructors are typically considered fair game for prototype tweaking so we can do things like add missing array methods in older IE for instance.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I allowed to declare prototypes in an object literal?

No.

> Or is there a way to do this if the example is not possible?

The only way to establish prototype inheritance is through a constructor or [`Object.create`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5). In both cases you can set the object to be used as the `[[Prototype]]` using an object literal, but you can't use an object literal to create the object instance and `[[Protoype]]` in the one literal.

Using a constructor:

```
function Obj() {
}

Obj.prototype = {
   sayHi: function(){
            alert('Hi');
   }
};

var obj = new Obj();
obj.sayHi();
```

Using Object.create

```
var obj = Object.create({sayHi: function(){alert('Hi');}});

var obj = Object.create(

  {sayHi: function(){alert('Hi');}},
  {
    init: {
      value: function(param) {
        alert(param);
      },
      writable: false
    }
  }
);


obj.sayHi();     // Hi
obj.init('foo'); // foo
```

Note that Object.create is ES5 so is not supported by older browsers (e.g. IE 7 and lower), but a fix is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).